# Размер шрифта при масштабировании

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Как заставить не вылазить текст за границу при масштабировании окна браузера?
Вот пример кода: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12xm150n/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header__today">
        <div class="current_date">
            <div class="current_date__day">23</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__today">
        <div class="current_date">
            <div class="current_date__day">23</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__today">
        <div class="current_date">
            <div class="current_date__day">23</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__today">
        <div class="current_date">
            <div class="current_date__day">23</div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.header__today {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  color: #fefefe;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: green;
}
.current_date {
    font-size: 150px;
    margin: 43px auto 0 32px;
    &__day {
      line-height: 150px;
      border: 1px solid #fefefe;
    }
}
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы 23 не вылазило за нарисованную границу либо чтобы 23 раздвигало border. С помощью js эту проблему решил, но хочется более правильного решения без использования js.

Comment: При увеличении масштаба? У меня что-то такое показывается: http://s06.radikal.ru/i179/1605/f8/a0ae77454385.png

Comment: Нет, я хочу чтобы блоки header__today пропорционально уменьшались и оставались в одном ряду. При этом нужно чтобы надпись 23 была всегда на виду внутри рамки.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Значит либо js либо медиазапросы.

Comment: Ну на самом деле посмотрите повнимательнее на кроссбраузерность, в большинстве случаев partitial support достаточно

Comment: Комментарии в ответ повыносил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если взять решения на чистом css, то:

**Во-первых**

Можно задать размер шрифта относительно [размеров области обзора (viewport).](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
Что-то типа:

```
.current_date {
    font-size: 10vw; /* подобрать размеры вручную, в зависимости от верстки*/
    /* все остальное */
}
```

**1vw** = 1% от ширины области обзора (viewport).
**1vh** = 1% от высоты области обзора (viewport).
**1vmin** = меньшее из 1vw, 1vh.
**1vmax** = большее из 1vw, 1vh.

Решение конечно [не супернадёжное](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), десяток разных известных ошибок, но очень удобное.

**Во-вторых**
Можно использовать [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) и менять размер шрифта самому в тех пороговых значениях где верстка начинает сыпаться, но по мне уж лучше js.

Comment: Ох, что это ещё за "вьюпорт" такой в русском языке?

Comment: @edem, мая плоха гаварить руски. Твая карашо - твая праветь)

Comment: Тут уместна известная фраза Станиславского: "Не верю!"; ну да ладно, поправить дело несложное, раз уж так.

Comment: @edem, я к тому что "вьюпорт" - это термин. Ну не знаю я, как его удачно перевести. "Область обзора" вроде обозначает, что надо. Но скажешь "область обзора" - переспросят, что имеешь в виду. Скажешь вьюпорт - поймут. Как говорят же обычно "это у нас синглтон", а не переводят.

Comment: Ну singleton, как правило называют "одиночка", а вообще да, проблема с переводом многих терминов существует, но лучше уж в оригинале писать термин, чем его произношение, если нет нормального перевода, то бишь vieport и т.п.